# query_vars in plugin not working?

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I have a problem writing a plugin for wordpress.
First, I register a new `query_var` and add a new rewrite rule:

```
function nng_users_query_vars( $vars ) {
    array_push( $vars, 'nng_users' );
    return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'nng_users_query_vars');

function nng_users_rewrite_rules( $rules ) {
$newrules = array(
                        'benutzer/([^/]+)/?$' => 'index.php?pagename=nng_users&nng_users=$matches[1]'
                      );
$finalrules = $newrules + $rules;
    return $finalrules;
}
add_filter('rewrite_rules_array','nng_users_rewrite_rules');
```

This works perfectly, but I cannot grab any `query_var` from the plugin. Typing:

```
print_r( $wp_query->query_var );
```

or

```
echo $wp_query->query_var['some_var'];
```

does not show anything. But why? If I put the exact same thing into the function of my theme, it works. If I put it into a function and call this function in my theme, it works...
Background is the following: I want to create a custom user system and therefore I need to check my custom query var to e.g. logout or header-redirect.

Thanks in advance

Comment: and of course I tried to global $wp_query

Comment: is `$wp_query->query_var` a typo? it's plural: `$wp_query->query_vars`

Comment: its a typo, sry about that. I used $wp_query->query_vars of course

Comment: have you found any solution? i am having same issue.

Answer (score -2):

Late answer, but for everybody else looking for it, this works:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_query_var

Comment: Kind of a pointless answer, just pointing to the doc for the function. You should at least post the relevant part of the code that helped you.